# Pyspark - Timezone issue when writing the dataframe to kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, timestamp-with-timezone

In my transformation I cast the dates as the following

```py
f.date_format(
       f.to_utc_timestamp(f.col("DATE"), "Europe/Paris"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
).alias("receipt_date"),
```

when writing my resulted `dataframe` to `json`

```py
  data_frame.write.mode("overwrite").option("ignoreNullFields", "false").format("json").save(path)
```

I got a **correct** output

> "receipt_date":"2022-07-07 00:00:00"

**But** when writing the dataframe to `kafka` I got the following output

> "receipt_date":"2022-07-06 22:00:00"

```py
 data_frame.selectExpr(
        "CAST(id AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(metadata,payload)) AS value"
    ).write.format("kafka")
```

Note: I run the job on AWS Glue and I alreday added this config

> --conf spark.sql.session.timeZone=Europe/Paris

Any suggestion please

Comment: It seems to be a miss-configuration (I compared the kafka  with the json output from different aws environements ! )

Comment: In the glue job of the other environment I put this config `--conf --conf spark.sql.session.timeZone=Europe/Paris` (I had to remove the first **--conf**)  thus everything is OK